# bytearray.reverse() not working within a class, is working when called on object

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-bytearray

I have a class where in the initialization I set one member to a bytearray, and then another to its reverse by using the bytearray.reverse() function.

When I instantiate the class, the "reversed" array is not reversed. If I then call reverse on the member after instantiation, it reverses fine. What is happening? class and ipython output is below

```
class Cipher():
  def __init__(self, key=bytearray(b'abc123y;')):
    self.setKeys(key)

  def setKeys(self, key):
    if isinstance(key, bytearray) and len(key) >= 8:
      self.encrKey = key[:8]
      self.decrKey = self.encrKey
      self.decrKey.reverse()
      print("Encrypt: ", self.encrKey)
      print("Decrypt: ", self.decrKey)
      return True
    else:
      return False

In [13]: cipher = Cipher()
Encrypt:  bytearray(b';y321cba')
Encrypt:  bytearray(b';y321cba')

In [14]: cipher.decrKey.reverse()

In [15]: cipher.decrKey
Out[15]: bytearray(b'abc123y;')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are acting on the same reference when you call `.reverse` on `self.decrKey` because you previously made the assignment:

```
self.decrKey = self.encrKey
```

As a result, you're reversing *both* `encrKey` and `decrKey`. Instead, copy `decrKey` with `[:]` and *then* call `.reverse`:

```
self.encrKey = key[:8]
self.decrKey = self.encrKey[:]
self.decrKey.reverse()
```

Comment: I thought it might be something like that, but ... why is it working after the object is instantiated?

Comment: @DanielB. it's working in both cases by reversing both attributes. See the output of `cipher.encrKey` after calling `cipher.decrKey.reverse()`; it changes too.

Comment: Ohhh. Well. I feel dumb. I guess I need to look into when python uses references rather than copies.